# Network Manager gsm connection

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tty, modem, networkmanager

I'm using nmcli to set up a connection to a 3g modem on the ttyAM0 port. Modem manager has no problem displaying info about the modem. Nmcli creates the connection no problem. But when I try to connect with this new connection I get this error.

```
Error: Connection activation failed.
```

So then I try to connect to the device (ttyACM0), but that gives me this error:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).
```

In /var/log/syslog I see error messages like these

```
pppd[12001]: Modem hangup
NetworkManager[892]: Modem hangup
device (ppp0): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
device (ttyACM0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
device (ttyACM0): Activation: failed for connection 'm2m'
```

I've successfully made a gsm connection with this same modem on other machines, but for some reason my process isn't working on this machine. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apprentely, I was using the wrong apn name when I made the connection. Once I started  using the correct apn the connection worked as expected.